# expenses,incomes and total balance calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I decided to make calculator that counts expenses, incomes and total balance(incomes - expenses)

```py
expenses = []
incomes = []


def add_expense(expense_name, expense_amount):
    expense = {expense_name: expense_amount}
    expenses.append(expense)


def add_income(income_name, income_amount):
    income = {income_name, income_amount}
    incomes.append(income)


def total_bal():
    for expense, income in expenses and incomes:
        total_expenses = sum(expense.values())
        total_income = sum(income.value())
        balance = total_income - total_expenses
        return balance


while True:
    choice = input('Choose ur variant: 1 - expenses | 2 - incomes | 0 - quit')
    if '1' in choice:
        expense_name = input('name of ur expense: ')
        expense_amount = int(input('amount of ur expense: '))
        add_expense(expense_name, expense_amount)

    elif '2' in choice:
        income_name = input('name of ur income: ')
        income_amount = int(input('name of ur income: '))
        add_income(income_name, income_amount)


    elif '0' in choice:
        break

bal = total_bal()
print(bal)
```

it works well until I type '0'

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: this is because `expense` is an integer. And the code uses `expense.values()`.....  but there are a lot more errors in the code beyond this..

Comment: There are multiple errors in your code. The most outstanding one is *for expense, income in expenses and incomes*. What do you think that does? btw - a copy'n'paste of your code (as shown) does **not** raise an AttributeError when the input is 0. Also, it's "your" not "ur". Why would an expense amount be an integer? Surely it should be *float*

Comment: the code does not require a for loop in the `total_bal()` function.